# Swift Starscream websocket pod not Connecting to local server and no delegate methods called

Tags: ios, websocket, swift2, starscream

I have been trying to connect to a local server without success. My Code is as follows -

```
class SocketManager: NSObject, WebSocketDelegate {
    var socket: WebSocket!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(string: "ws://localhost:9292/")!)
        self.socket.delegate = self
        print("TRYING TO CONNECT")
        self.socket.connect()
        print("DONE TRYING")
    }

    func websocketDidConnect(ws: WebSocket) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(ws: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
         print("websocket is disconnected: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(ws: WebSocket, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(ws: WebSocket, data: NSData) {
         print("Received data: \(data.length)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceivePong(socket: WebSocket) {
        print("Got pong!")
    }
}
```

Both the Print statements "TRYING TO CONNECT" and "DONE TRYING" are present in the log, but none of the delegate methods seem to be called.

I am not sure what could be wrong here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: I posted an answer for the issue, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that, I was creating an instance of the class `SocketManager` in the AppDelegate and that variable was falling out of scope.

To solve this, I created an instance variable in the `AppDelegate`, after doing that the delegate methods are being called as expected.

Here's a link to the issue that I posted on their Github repo.

https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/203

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still confused, the problem (for me) was that I was initialising and calling everything in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let client = WsClient(echoURL: "ws://localhost:8000/")
client.connect()
client.socket.write(string: "Hi Server!")
```

To fix this, I simply moved the `client` definition to be a property of `ViewController`, while keeping `connect` and `write` in `viewDidLoad`. This worked!

So now I have

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let client = WsClient(echoURL: "ws://localhost:8000/")
    (...)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        client.connect()
        client.socket.write(string: "Hi Server!")
    }
}
```